# NextJs meta tag in next/head not available to Facebook and metatags.io

Tags: next.js, seo

I create a component SeoHeader to handle meta tag creation on NextJs project

```
import React from 'react';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { useRouter } from 'next/dist/client/router';

const SeoHeader = ({ title, description, image }) => {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <Head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      <meta charSet="utf-8" />

      <meta name="description" content={description} key="description" />

      <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
      <meta property="og:title" content={title} key="og:title" />
      <meta property="og:description" content={description} key="og:description" />
      <meta property="og:image" content={image} key="og:image" />
      <meta property="og:url" content={`https://www.energici.fr${router?.asPath}`} key="og:url" />
      <meta name="twitter:card" content={description} key="twitter:card" />

      <meta property="og:site_name" content="Energici, l'info bien être" key="og:site_name" />

      <meta
        property="twitter:url"
        content={`https://www.energici.fr${router?.asPath}`}
        key="twitter:url"
      />
      <meta
        name="twitter:image:alt"
        content="Energici la plateforme du bien être"
        key="twitter:image:alt"
      />
      <meta property="twitter:domain" content="energici.fr" />

      <title>{title}</title>
    </Head>
  );
};

export default SeoHeader;
```

If I import this component on _app.js everything is going well. I can see the meta tags in html dom and if I share the link preview card is ok.
But if I share another page for example this one : https://www.energici.fr/decouvrons-la-kinesiologie
I can see the correct meta tag in html dom but if I share the link in facebook for example or if I test it here https://metatags.io/ I cannot se anything, it's like there is no meta tag.

Any idea ?

Comment: Note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: This is JSX and so it is required to close tags in React.

Comment: I know it's late, I was having the same problem. Found a solution. I you setup the head tags in the Component, then it won't be ready before using Javascript. Instead,  in `getServerSideProps`, fetch the data you want (if necessary) and pass the title, desc, image info to props in `return { props }`. Those props can be receive in `_app.js` `props.pageProps`. Here you add those info in their tags in `<Head>...</Head>`. In `_app.js` the HEAD tags are transformed directly in HTML with no JS needed to display them. But in `props.Component`, they will need JS.

Answer (score 0):

Neither the crawler for Facebook, nor the crawler for metatags.io can execute JavaScript.   Any HTML tags that are inserted by client side JavaScript won't be available to them.

Googlebot *can* execute JavaScript, so your meta data may work for Google.  The caveat is that Googlebot has to render your pages, so crawling and indexing can take weeks longer than it would otherwise.

You can solve these problems by [prerendering your site](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#pre-rendering).  After implementing that, crawlers will see HTML with your tags and not have to run JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This os what I done because my component in on page that is pre redered (getStaticProps)

Comment: If you view-source on the page in your browsers you can see all your meta tags?

Comment: Yes I do, I can see all the meta tag

Comment: If you share your URL on Facebook with a dummy URL parameter, does that help? Sometimes it's a matter of cashing where the Facebook servers don't fetch the latest version of your page and just rely on what they fetched a while ago.

Comment: No it doesn't change anything

Comment: It looks fine in Facebook's sharing debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.energici.fr%2Fdecouvrons-la-kinesiologie